# Python: memory usage statistics per object-types (or source code line)

Tags: python, debugging, memory, memory-leaks

I am doing some heavy calculations with Python (using OpenCV and Numpy) and in the end, I end up with a lot of memory usage (>1GB) whereby all refs should be gone and I only have the end-result (which should not be more than a few MB).

To debug this, it would be nice if I could get some stats somehow which show me how much object instances there are of what type, ordered by the total amount of memory they take (per object class).

Or even nicer: Not per object class but per source code line where the object was created (whereby I guess this info is not available unless I activate some debugging in Python which would make the calculation too slow, so I am not sure if that would be helpful).

Can I get some stats like this somehow? Or how would I debug this?

---

Some has missunderstood me: I *only* need to know how to debug the memory usage. Processing/run- time is perfect.

Comment: For starters, see http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but look at \_\_slots\_\_ for reducing memory consumption a lot.

Comment: @Rafe: This only seems to be about the runtime but not about the memory usage, doesn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're searching for a python profiler ;

you have a bunch of them that you can use , like [Heapy](https://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy), [profile or cprofile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) , [Pysize](https://pysizer.8325.org/) ...

**example using Heapy :**

you have to include this snippet somewhere in your code:

```
from guppy import hpy
h = hpy()
print h.heap()
```

and it will give you as output:

```
Partition of a set of 132527 objects. Total size = 8301532 bytes.
Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
0  35144  27  2140412  26   2140412  26 str
1  38397  29  1309020  16   3449432  42 tuple
2    530   0   739856   9   4189288  50 dict (no owner)
```

**example with cprofile :**

you can run it like this:

```
python -m cProfile script.py
```

Output:

```
         5 function calls in 0.000 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 myscript.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {execfile}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
```

You can also use [gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) module to know why python is not freeing your memory, and to ask him to free memory using [gc.collect()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect).

By the way have you looked at [numpy](https://numpy.org/), i think it more suitable if you're doing heavy calculation like you said.

Comment: I don't quite see how I can get memory stats out of cProfile. Can you explain?

Comment: Heapy seems more useful from what it shows. However, it doesn't seem to give correct output. It says that the total size is about 8MB. But the process takes about >1GB.

Comment: I was using the tools in objgraph (described [here](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks)) and it gives me similar output. But I wonder why it doesn't show any `str` references. However, both fail to show where most of the memory actually is (about 99% of the real memory is missing in the output). Maybe it is a memory leak in one of the external libraries like OpenCV or Numpy?

Comment: @Albert: about __cprofile__ it can give some info about where to look to see where it spend more time doing calculation , and for __heapy__ what i gived you in my example was the easiest way to do it you have to look at the doc (http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/) to find out how to enable some option that may give you more detail about memory usage

Comment: @Albert: look also at gc module if they are some memory leak you can find them also using gc.garbage() , and look also in your code if you can found some reference cycles that may not let the GC free your memory and also try to use weakref module.

Comment: Ah sorry, I maybe should have been more clear. The calculation time is not an issue at all. Only the memory usage at the end is wrong.

Comment: Ok, it seems that Heapy also cannot find the memory. I guess this proves that the memory must be used by some of the libs (I guess OpenCV).

Comment: @Albert :hmmm !! yes i think so too , i don't think heapy or either of the python profiler can look at third party library, however you can use the unix command pstat it can give you some more information regarding all the memory usage , and goo luck :)

Comment: @mouad do you mean `pmap`? or `iostat`? I can't seem to find reference to a `pstat` command (and neither will Google - changes search to iostat)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I hunted it down. As none of the Python mem profiles give any helpful output (because they couldn't find the memory), I was quite sure that some of the external libs (OpenCV) were the source of the mem leak.

And I could reproduce the mem leak with this simple code:

```
import cv
while True: cv.CreateHist([40], cv.CV_HIST_ARRAY, [[0,255]], 1)
```

---

Some of the other resources for Python mem debugging which were quite interesting (didn't helped in that case but may be useful for others):

- [Tracing Python memory leaks](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks)
- [Python object graphs](http://mg.pov.lt/blog/python-object-graphs.html)
- [Hunting memory leaks in Python](http://mg.pov.lt/blog/hunting-python-memleaks.html)
- [Object graphs with graphviz](http://mg.pov.lt/blog/object-graphs-with-graphviz.html)