# Eclipse memory view for Python code

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am coding with Eclipse PyDev. When I tried to use the Eclipse memory view in order to see the memory allocation of objects in Python, the view is empty and no action is allowed (as shown in the picture). I know that this is available for other programming languages as for example C, C++...

[image]

I found [this post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/957976/) in Eclipse forums, basically it says that as PyDev is an external product to Eclipse the memory view implementation depends on PyDev.

On the other side, the [PyDev documentation site](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html) does not explain anything about memory view.

So, if I am interested in viewing the memory information of Python objects when debugging:

- Is there any possible way to do this with PyDev and Eclipse?
- Can this be done with other IDEs or tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev does not make use of the memory view in any way (that feature isn't really available in PyDev).

If you're on a newer Python, you may want to check:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html

And there are also some other interesting links you can see:

http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python.html

[Python: memory usage statistics per object-types (or source code line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178116/python-memory-usage-statistics-per-object-types-or-source-code-line)