# Without any change, my python application eats up my RAM

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

My python application used to run fine for weeks, and it'd never take up any significant amount of RAM. But as of the last few weeks, without changing a single line, it'll take up 16GB of RAM within a few hours.

I'm guessing this is probably a library or python issue, but considering my application is relatively complex, I have no idea where to even start looking for the problem.

How should I go about debugging this kind of problem?

Comment: I would profile the application to see what is exactly what objects are consuming the memory. See this answer for techniques on how to do this in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178216/668797.

Comment: Is there any way to profile external libraries? I don't think my application is the problem here, since it worked fine before (without changing a single line).

Comment: Did the versions of the external libraries change? For instance, reinstalling python on a new machine? My impression reading this was that the data processed by the application changed somehow to cause this behavior.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time someone said they didn't change anything....

Comment: @BradMcDanel Indeed, that's what I'm trying to find, to see which libraries have changed. So far, I haven't found much

Comment: Interestingly enough, I tried using massif, and there weren't any memory issues (it used 20MB RAM max), vs in a smaller amount of time (without running massif), the application is now taking 200MB.